# I need to put “noindex,nofollow” for all woocommerce urls

Tags: woocommerce

I set it to noindex with Seo Yoast but cant set it to nofollow.
I need to put “noindex,nofollow” for all woocommerce urls contains category, tag, product and etc.
What solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'heder_noindex_tag');

function heder_noindex_tag(){
    if (is_woocommerce() || is_checkout() || is_cart()){
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. it worked.
how to set rel "nofollow" to all product urls or tag or categories?

Comment: is_woocommerce should cover these cases. But if not, you can always refer to this article about conditional tags: https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/